# Using java collections in spark programs

Tags: apache-spark

I have a doubt in using java collections in spark programs? I got to know the following from spark programming guide.

The first way to reduce memory consumption is to avoid the Java features that add overhead, such as pointer-based data structures and wrapper objects. There are several ways to do this:

Design your data structures to prefer arrays of objects, and primitive types, instead of the standard Java or Scala collection classes (e.g. HashMap). The fastutil library provides convenient collection classes for primitive types that are compatible with the Java standard library.

Does this mean we shouldn't use java collections instead we must go for array of objects? Is the following code fine?

```
Map<String, String> lookUpMap = getLkp(path);
final Broadcast<<Map<String, String>> lookupBrdcst = sparkContext.broadcast(lookUpMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fine, assuming the size of the HashMap isn't too large. If it gets large you would probably want to use a join.

Your code does have a slight syntax error:

`final Broadcast<<Map<String, String>> lookupBrdcst = sparkContext.broadcast(lookUpMap);`

should be:

`final Broadcast<Map<String, String>> lookupBrdcst = sparkContext.broadcast(lookUpMap);`

You can see Java collections used as broadcast variables in the Spark examples themselves:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaRecoverableNetworkWordCount.java

This example uses `List<String>` as a broadcast variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. My hashmap is not that big. Can you please be more clear on the point "If it gets large, you would probably want to use a join" ? I am quite new to spark. Will it consume more memory than array of strings?

Comment: Its mainly the difference between doing an in-memory join on a small dataset vs a large join. A Map will use more memory than a String array, but really I would focus on how many entries you have. For example if the Map has 100K entries I would just try it, if it was in the millions you can try it, but you might be getting into the region where an actual join is required.